# Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to... must be an instance of - Magento 2.2.1

Tags: magento2, admin, customer-account

I'm trying to create a tab within the customer section of admin by following this tutorial: http://www.ibnab.com/en/blog/magento-2/magento-2-backend-create-custom-tab-in-customer-view-and-load-grid-inside-admin.

When i try to reach my controller:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught TypeError: Argument 2 passed to Magento\\Customer\\Controller\\Adminhtml\\Index::__construct() must be an instance of Magento\\Framework\\Registry, none given, called in /var/www/mage2/public_html/generated/code/Vendor/Module/Controller/Adminhtml/Index/Index/Interceptor.php on line 14
```

I have a basic controller working however using the above tutorials controller i get that error when extending the controller to use the **\Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index** class. I have tried clearing **di** and **generation** folders but the error persists.

> **Basic Working Controller:**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\TestFramework\ErrorLog\Logger;

class Index extends \Magento\Backend\App\Action
{
    public function execute()
    {

        $this->_view->loadLayout();
        $this->_view->getLayout()->initMessages();
        $this->_view->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

> **This controller doesn't work:**

```
namespace Vendor\Module\Controller\Adminhtml\Index;

use Magento\Backend\App\Action;
use Magento\TestFramework\ErrorLog\Logger;

class Index extends \Magento\Customer\Controller\Adminhtml\Index
{

     * Customer compare grid
     *
     * @return \Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout

    public function execute()
    {
        $this->initCurrentCustomer();
        $resultLayout = $this->resultLayoutFactory->create();
        return $resultLayout;
    }
}
```

As previously stated it seems to break when changing the class that the controller is extending.

Comment: your version is magento 2.2?

Comment: Yeah sorry 2.2.1

Comment: Did you remove generation and var folder from root?

Comment: I cleared var/generation/* var/di/*

Comment: in root generated folder exitst please remove it not var/generation

Comment: Yeah think it has looking at that error acutally

Comment: My hero :P post that as an answer i shall accept

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whenever you declare dependency injection class in your constructor for php file for creating module,

**For Magento 2.0.* and 2.1.***

```
You must need to remove var/generation folder content
```

**For Magento 2.2.***

> You must need to remove var folder and generated folder content except
>   .htacess file from root.

Now you can check your module no any inception generated file error shown.

Comment: So this has changed since the 2.2.x release?

Comment: Yes since 2.2.x  new generated folder are available in root for interception/factory class

Comment: ah yeah i thought something was up as could always fix the error clearing them old folders. Cheers for this

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and resolving it by following steps

First, you need to remove generated/code/* and var/cache/*

```
rm -rf generated/code/* var/cache/*
```

Second, Clean the cache

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Third, Change the file permission

```
sudo chmod 777 -R generated/ var/ pub/
```

Fourth, run Generated Compile the code

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
```